# react native scroll to a listview item programmatically

Tags: listview, scroll, react-native

I have a horizontal ListView each item of the ListView occupy the whole width and height and same for the second item and so on ( it's like a horizontal pagination ), after implementing it I want to scroll to the next item programmatically, so I disabled scrolling `scrollEnabled={false}` now I want to scroll programmatically ( after triggering an event ) to the next item (page), any hint or idea for this one?

**UPD**

This the error caused by scrollTo : `scrollTo is not defined`

```
<Button title="Learn More"
  onPress = {(ev)=>{
     scrollTo(0, 1000)
  }}></Button>
```

Comment: `scrollTo` function would be best possible way to achieve this.

Comment: @SagarKhatri I'd did use it inside a function "renderRow()" but I'm getting scrollTo in not defined!

Comment: @AbdenaceurLichiheb If you're getting that error (and not only in this case) is better to showing us the code :)

Comment: ok. This is more a javascript related error. `scrollTo(0, 1000)` is not defined because the context of that call is that arrow function and not the component.
So you need a reference to the ListView and then you can do like: `listview.scrollTo(0, 1000)`

Comment: @LS05 Thanks but how to get a reference of the listview should I call new ListView() inside my constructor? ( sorry I'm weak with javascript I only have java background )

Comment: @AbdenaceurLichiheb Just for reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Answer (score 2):

**1. Try to get a reference to the scroll view**

This is how I do it:

```
render(){
  let _listView: ListView;
  return (          
      <ListView ref={(listView) => { _listView = listView; }}
            dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
            renderRow={this._renderRow.bind(this)}
      />
  )
}
```

**2. Using the `_listView` variable and calling the `scrollTo` method.**

Note that you're using it in an arrow function and in my code above, the `_listView` variable is inside the `render` method. So you can create it inside the constructor and then use it as a class property.

Like this:

```
constructor() {
  this._listView = {};
}
```

(Note that this is an example initialization, I don't know where you're using that button, so probably this second point is not necessary or even wrong, so everything could be done inside the render method).

Comment: I already fix it I just forgot to add ref="listview" to my listview, thanks :)